# mysqldump large db incrementally

Tags: database, mysql

I have a rather large db(2TB) that I wish to dump incrementally(range dump or something).
is it possible to do it using mysqldump? if not, what should I use?

Comment: i would recommend to dump in batches using mysqldump - separate DB/Tables

Comment: @GinoSullivan: so I would have to dump a whole table at a time?  The issue here is that each table is very large and I want to dump the rows in range or incrementally.

Comment: what do you whant to achieve ? only multiple files of the whole dump ? then you can pipe the mysqldump call through `split`

Comment: A similar question found here `http://serverfault.com/questions/256051/incremental-differential-mysql-backup-using-mysqldump`

Answer (score 3):

[mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html) will allow you to dump "databases" or tables individually using the --databases and **--tables** options.  You can use a script that will fetch the table names from [TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html) in INFORMATION_SCHEMA and provide those parameters when invoking mysqldump.

To specify the range of rows, for partial table dumps, use the **--where** option. The --lock-tables/--single-transaction option can be used to block changes to the tables while dumping.  Please consult the manual as those options are used in different situations.

With a powerful scripting language, i.e. Python, you can creatively invoke mysqldump to best tackle your problem.